# Why $\mathbf r''(t) \cdot \mathbf r'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2} \mathbf r'(t)\cdot \mathbf r'(t))$ is true?

Tags: calculus, physics

I have trouble of understanding proof of work-energy formula. This formula is from  Salas's and Hill's calculus textbook.
There is one step that I don't understand.
$\mathbf r''(t) \cdot \mathbf r'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2} \mathbf r'(t)\cdot \mathbf r'(t))$
Why it is valid?

That is why aceleration vector and velocity vectors dot product is half of velocity vector squared?

Comment: Recall the product rule:$$\frac{d}{dt}(\mathbf a(t)\cdot\mathbf b(t)) = \frac{d\mathbf a(t)}{dt}\cdot\mathbf b(t) + \mathbf a(t)\cdot\frac{d\mathbf b(t)}{dt}$$

Comment: That's a simple application of the product rule.  Try differentiation of the RHS, you should get the LHS

Comment: It's [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule): $(ab)'=a'b+ab'$ applied to $a=b=r'$.

Comment: Thank you. Main point is to think from answer to question, I was unable to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the product rule:
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}(uv)=u\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}+v\dfrac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}$$
Putting in $u=v=\mathbf{r}'$, we get
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\Big(\mathbf{r}'(t)\cdot\mathbf{r}'(t)\Big)=2\mathbf{r}'(t)\cdot\mathbf r''(t)$$
Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)